# Redirecting to wrong path Phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

Just started using Phalcon, and found some strange error.

Here is my code in `public/index.php`

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlProvider;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;



// Register an autoloader
$loader = new Loader();

$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        "../app/controllers/",
        "../app/models/",
    ]
);

$loader->register();



// Create a DI
$di = new FactoryDefault();

// Setup the view component
$di->set(
    "view",
    function () {
        $view = new View();

        $view->setViewsDir("../app/views/");

        return $view;
    }
);

// Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "bot" folder
$di->set(
    'url', 
    function() {
        $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/bot/');
        return $url;
    }
);


$application = new Application($di);

try {
    // Handle the request
    $response = $application->handle();

    $response->send();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

According to this, my path should be `localhost/bot/`.

But, when I type it in, I get this [image]

So, when I navigate to `localhost/bot/public/`, I get the desired output.

Why is it not behaving the way as given in the website?

Answer (score 2):

You need `.htaccess` in bot directory which will pass all requests to `public/index.php`

Something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or similar nginx configuration.